# Get max price date for a product within a given period (mysql)

Tags: mysql, join

My mysql table with prices

```
+----------+-----+----------+
|product_id|price|date_at   |
+----------+-----+----------+
|   1      |41.50|2020-09-01|
|   1      |99.50|2020-09-02|
|   1      |41.50|2020-09-03|
|   1      |41.50|2020-09-04|
|   1      |41.50|2020-09-05|
|   1      |9.90 |2020-09-06|
+----------+-----+----------+
```

I can get today and yesterday prices:

```
select today.price,
       yesterday.price as yesterday_price
from prices today
         left join prices yesterday on today.product_id = yesterday.product_id
where yesterday.date_at = '2020-09-05' <-- I need to have it dynamic
  and today.date_at = '2020-09-06'
```

I need to have yesterday date as any date from period N days with MAX(price).

Example:
yesterday.date_at = last 20 days max price for the same product_id

Maybe I should use more code in left join instead of where.
Please tell me how to change my query.

Comment: It is hard to say what you are asking for. Let me guess: (i) You give the query a number e.g. 20, (ii) the query returns the date where the price was maximum between 20 days ago till today. Right?

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: Maybe you should provide the desired result, along with a properly representative data set. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what you want to do is something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(price) FROM prices
WHERE date_at BETWEEN _from_date AND _to_date
      AND product_id = _product_id;
```

You have to hard type the parameters (_from_date; to_date; and _product_id). Should you want to make it dynamic, you will have to think about writing an equivalent stored procedure